# Unusual Response for simple json render with active model serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I have the following files in my Rails 4 project:

**lists_controller.rb**

```
class Api::V1::ListsController < Api::V1::ApiController
  before_action :set_list, only: [:show]

  attr_accessor :list

  def show
    respond_with list
  end

  private

  def set_list
    @list = List.where(id: params[:id]).first
    render_list_not_found if @list.nil?
  end

  def render_list_not_found
    render json: { "list" => { message: "List not found" } }, status: 404
  end

end
```

**list_serializer.rb**

```
class ListSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids, include: true

  attributes :id, :title, :start_date, :end_date

  has_many :items
end
```

When I hit the API with an id for a list that exists, I get the correct json back. But when you pass an invalid id, you'd think you'd get this back:

```
 {
  "list": {
     "message": "List not found"
   }
 }
```

but instead get this:

```
 {
    "lists": [
        [
            "list",
            [
                [
                    "message",
                    "List not found."
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the active model serializers was being invoked even with the simple render. I was using version `0.9.1` of the gem, but downgrading to `0.9.0` seem to do the trick. Very strange.